# What to do if people can't ping me?

Tags: networking, ping

Today, I installed my new router so I can connect my other pc and my ps3. In my network,  there are some other computers these are connected with each other through another router. So I have one modem with 2 routers that make up my network. Everything works fine the only problem I am having is being pinged by other computers in the network. All the computers are on the same subnet 255.255.255.0. There is no problem with my firewall or anything I tested everything.

How can I solve this?

Comment: firewall problem....you say it isn't but it is

Comment: I tried pinging my pc which doesnt even have a firewall (archlinux) and that didn't work. I can ping computers on the same router and i can be pinged by them.

Comment: It may help to describe your setup more precisely: IP addresses, topology (between what are there cables), router model and configuration (especially routing tables and packet filtering rules). Terminology note: 255.255.255.0 would be the netmask, a subnet is a set of IP addresses commonly written as e.g. 192.168.1.0/24 (/24 implies a netmask of 255.255.255.0).

Comment: Exactly how did you test your firewall?